# Problem with taking input from user in a function

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I am creating a program that takes in the input for students' names and 4 test scores and prints them out in the grid. This is done in the void function `insert_data`. At some point in the function when it takes in the input for the second student the name is skipped, going straight to the scores which is creating problems when feeding in the input through a textfile. I provided a representation of my code, along with the output given when I enter the data by hand. I am using pointers to do everything and would prefer to keep them that way. I've also used fgets and that doesn't seem to be helping either. Any help here?

```
int main() {
    int i, score[5][MAX_SCORES];
    char names[5][NAME_MAX];

    int (*pscore)[MAX_SCORES] = score;
    char (*pnames)[NAME_MAX] = names;

    insert_data(pnames, pscore);

    return 0;
}

void insert_data(char (*pnames)[NAME_MAX], int (*pscore)[MAX_SCORES]) {
    int i, j;
    // taking input

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++){
        printf("Enter student %d name:", i + 1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s",*(pnames + i));

        for (j = 0; j < MAX_SCORES; j++) {
            printf("Enter student %d score: ", (i + 1));
            scanf("%d", *(pscore + i) + j);
            printf("%d\n",*(*(pscore + i) + j) );
        }
    }    
      // printing grid
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++) {
        printf("%s: \t\t",*(pnames + i));

        for (j = 0; j < MAX_SCORES; j++) {
            printf("%d \t",*(*(pscore + i) + j));

        }
        printf("\n");
}
}
```

output looks like this:

```
Enter student 1 name:John Doe
    Enter student 1 score: 56
    56
    Enter student 1 score: 34
    34
    Enter student 1 score: 23
    23
    Enter student 1 score: 76
    76
    Enter student 2 name:Enter student 2 score: 67
    67
    Enter student 2 score: 67
    67
    Enter student 2 score: 34
    34
    Enter student 2 score: 65
    65
    Enter student 3 name:Enter student 3 score:
```

it completely skips the name input after the first name.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the format string in this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",*(pnames + i));
```

at least the following way

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",*(pnames + i));
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

The problem is that after entering integers the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

Also remove the trailing symbol `s` in the format string.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. I was not attentive.:)